# SNS subscriptions are not displayed in SNS topic details page

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, aws-cdk

Let's say I have a SNS created a topic name `topic-1` and a queue `my-lambda-queue` using CDK (python) which subscribe to `topic-1`. After some time the messages stop getting delivered to `my-lambda-queue`. If the remove the subscriptions and try adding them again then messages start to deliver.

Upon investigation I found that, the SNS topic `topic-1` details page on AWS console does not show the subscription for `my-lambda-queue` but on the SQS details page of `my-lambda-queue` the subscription is shown.

This is strange, can someone please guide me where I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share your code? Do you have a re-drive policy (DLQ) enabled?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue, in my case it was due to an unconfirmed Subscription from SNS, and then creating a Subscription request from the SQS caused the subscription to not show up in the console even though it was a 'Successful subscription'

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50374308/3546389

This helped fix it.